# What does "exhausted" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Tang, 2004](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305048303001336) said that

> Standard textbooks of Investment/Financial Management teach that
> although portfolio diversification can help reduce investment risk
> without sacrificing the expected rate of return, the benefit of
> diversication is exhausted with a portfolio size of 10–15

I understand that most of the diversifiable risk can be achieved by having from 15-20 stocks in a portfolio. But the word" exhausted" really confused me.

From Cambridge, it is nothing more than a [synonym](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exhausted) of  "very tired"

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhausted#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20completely%20or%20almost%20completely,was%20just%20exhausted%2C%20totally%20exhausted.), it is almost the same with an addition meaning that the benefit of the source being depleted.

**I am from a country that English is not the mother language so it is hard for me to understand in this case. I mean, is it the same that we replace the word "exhausted" in Tang,2004 by "greatest"? I mean, the benefit of diversification is at its best in the portfolio of 10-15 stocks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you use "15-20 stocks" in your question when the passage uses "10-15." Those are not the same at all.

Regardless, the meaning is a somewhat metaphorical use of [sense 2 at wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhausted):

> Depleted of resources.
> *The **exhausted** mine was worthless once all the ore had been extracted.*

In your passage, **the benefit is exhausted** means **there is no more benefit**. That is, diversification provides a benefit *until you have 10-15 stocks*. Once you have that number of stocks, diversifying more does not give better results.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation. I used "stocks" here for the ease of explanation purpose. "Stocks" is also an object that the author mention in his/her paper

Comment: I was referring to the number. You said 15-20 but the author said 10-15.

Comment: edited, thanks :D